# (ARM assembly) Fastest way to access banked registers between processor modes?

Tags: assembly, optimization, arm, embedded, micro-optimization

I'm writing an interrupt service routine for an RTOS. At the beginning of an ISR, the ARM registers **LR_irq**, **LR_svc**, **R12**-**R0**, and **SPSR_irq** must be pushed to the interrupted task's stack *in exactly that order*. All tasks run in supervisor (*svc*) mode, so the registers are stacked using the **SP_svc** stack pointer. I've written the following assembly:

```
SRSFD   SP!, #0x13                                          @     Push the IRQ banked SPSR_irq and LR_irq registers to the SVC stack (in the order written)
CPS     #0x13                                               @     Enter supervisor mode to store the remaining registers on the SVC stack

STMFD   SP, {R0-R12}                                        @     Store remaining registers

                                                            @     REARRANGING                                       
LDMFD   SP!, {R0}                                           @     LR_irq => R0
LDMFD   SP!, {R1}                                           @     SPSR => R1
STMFD   SP!, {R0}                                           @     Push LR_irq and then the LR_svc
STMFD   SP!, {LR}                                           @     Push LR_svc

SUB     SP, SP, #52                                         @     Move back to the top of the stack

STMFD   SP!, {R1}                                           @     Push SPSR to the stack in the correct place (it needs to be at the top)
```

In summary, an interrupt occurs, the processor vectors to the code shown above in *irq* mode, and the following steps take place:

1. *SRSFD* pushes the **LR_irq** and **SPSR_irq** registers onto the interrupted task's stack (0x13 denotes *svc* mode, so the **SP_svc** stack pointer is used).
2. *CPS* moves the processor from *irq* mode to *svc* mode.
3. *STMFD* stacks **R0**-**R12** using the **SP_svc** stack pointer, since we're now in *svc* mode.
4. **NOT SO GOOD**: Because the registers in Step 1 were not pushed in the correct order, I now have to rearrange the stack.

Basically, I'm wondering if there's a way to accomplish this without the rearranging step. *Is there a more flexible instruction than SRSFD that could stack banked irq registers using the svc stack pointer in the correct order?*

Comment: I think your first bullet point has a typo.  It's [`SRSFD`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489g/Cihfdedi.html) not `STMFD` that runs before `CPS`.

Comment: Instead of `LDMFD` / `STMFD`, you could just use regular addressing modes with plain store/load instructions to swap the locations pushed by `srsfd`.  And you could use `stmfd sp!` to push r0-r12 because you can use an offset to reach back up into the stack.